# Compress a bitstring using Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, compression, bit

For a Bioinformatics project I need to compress a large amount of bitstrings (strings containing only 0's and 1's) in **Ruby** to smaller strings to reduce memory usage.

So ideally a string like "0001010010010010010001001" becomes something like "2a452c66". I first used MD5 hashes until I read something about possible collisions which I would like to avoid.

I have tried a lot of different combinations of unpack, to_i, to_s, etc, but can't seem to get the right combination.

The solution should:

- Keep any leading 0's.
- Be reversible.
- Compress (obviously).
- And the output should avoid strange characters. Preferably I would like to stay in the alphanumeric space. (a-zA-Z0-9).

Thanks!

Comment: Just for the record MD5 isn't reversible (no cryptographic hashes are) and you're very unlikely to get accidental collisions.

Comment: I was aware that md5 isn't reversible but was willing to live with that if I would have been unable to find a better solution. But since my search space is huge (2^112) I thought it better to avoid even a theoretical collision. Thanks for the info though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
FORMAT = '%0.*b'

bitmask = "0001010010010010010001001"
bitmask.to_i(2) # => 2696329
hexval = bitmask.to_i(2).to_s(16) # => "292489"
FORMAT % [bitmask.size, hexval.to_i(16)] # => "0001010010010010010001001"
```

What it's doing is:

- `to_i(2)` converts the string from binary to its integer value just to show what's happening.
- `to_i(2).to_s(16)` converts it to its hexadecimal representation as a string.
- `FORMAT` contains a `printf` format string saying to convert the passed in value into its binary string representation (`%b`) with leading `0` bytes (`%0b`) for an unknown length (`%0.*b`) which it gets from the first parameter passed (`bitmask.size`).

Here's another example using a longer bitmask:

```
bitmask = "11011110101011011011111011101111"

hexval = bitmask.to_i(2).to_s(16) # => "deadbeef"
FORMAT % [bitmask.size, hexval.to_i(16)] # => "11011110101011011011111011101111"
```

And longer still:

```
bitmask = "1101111010101101101111101110111111111110111011011010110111011010"

hexval = bitmask.to_i(2).to_s(16) # => "deadbeeffeedadda"
FORMAT % [bitmask.size, hexval.to_i(16)] # => "1101111010101101101111101110111111111110111011011010110111011010"
```

Comment: I now looked at the to_s documentation. Is there a disadvantage to using to_s(36) to compress even further?

Comment: Probably not, it's just not going to return values that are easily understood by human eyes. That's the advantage of looking at hex, it's a direct representation of binary, if you know how to do it of course.

Answer (score 3):

Just an interesting observation: If you want to convert a base-2 string into a higher base (say base-n), the compression ratio is `1/log2(n)`. This means that if you convert to hex as the other answer suggests, you'll get compression of 25% of the original. Moving all the way up to base 64 (only 2 more symbols than pure alphanumeric) you'll jump to about 17% compression. It just depends where you want to sit on that tradeoff!

Alternatively, if you *could* get rid of the reversibility requirement, only preserving equality, MD5 would be fine. See [How many random elements before MD5 produces collisions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201705/how-many-random-elements-before-md5-produces-collisions) spoiler: it's a lot. The collision "problems" you will read about are *purposeful* collisions; cryptographers using their knowledge of MD5 to *find* collisions. Accidental collisions are impossible for all practical purposes.

### Update

In terms of actually implementing a base64 encode in Ruby, I don't know. I don't actually know Ruby. What I'd do if it's not natively supported is **make an array of all the alphanumeric characters + 2** (so the array is 64 long) and then **convert chunks of 6 binary digits into the corresponding character** by **using that 6 digit binary number as an index** in the character array. If you wanted to use 62 (or any other non-power-of-two) then the algorithm would be different.

Comment: I read in the documentation that Ruby is only able to encode up to base36. Is it possible to go to base 64? Or 62 to stay in alphanumeric?