# Hash a string for duplicate detection

Tags: c#, hash

I'm writing a C# API which stored `SWIFT` messages types. I need to write a class that takes the entire string message and create a hash of it, store this hash in the database, so that when a new message is processed, it creates another hash, and checks this hash against ones in the database.

I have the following

```
 public static byte[] GetHash(string inputString)
 {
     HashAlgorithm algorithm = MD5.Create();  // SHA1.Create()
     return algorithm.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputString));
 }
```

and I need to know, if this will do?

***Global Comment****

So, I receive the files in a secure network, so we have full control over their validity - What I need to control is duplicate payments being made. I could split the record down into it's respective tag elemenents (SWFIT terminology) and then check them individually, but this then need to compare against records in the database, and the cost isn't something that can happen.

I need to check if the entire message is a duplicate of a message already processed, which is why i used this approach.

Comment: you have to keep in mind that given enough sample of data, you will run into a collision with md5. What probably would be better is to just create a UNIQUE column in your database.

Comment: @Puciek I don't think identity column in a DB would solve his issue since he wants a unique hash per unique message content, not just unique per message.

Comment: Depends on how many strings you expect to store. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201705/how-many-random-elements-before-md5-produces-collisions) for a discussion of collision probabilities.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you are asking in the question. Can you re-phrase your question to be more specific?

Comment: @kay.one and what stops you from splitting the message from message content into two columns the same way you split the hash from message?

Comment: Collisions are a possibility with MD5, but as Matt says it depends on the volume.  Still, SHA-2 512 would be a much better choice.

Comment: This will do _a_ hash, but it is not clear if it will do _the_ hash you want.

Comment: the probability of running into a collision is so low that you can probably gamble it or put it into context of everything else that can go wrong...

Comment: @BobProvencher Collisions aren't just going to happen randomly, most likely. They're usually a calculated effort and that would be considered an attack on the system, which is outside the scope of the question.

Comment: @Puciek maybe I misunderstood your first comment, did you mean to put a UNIQUE Constraint on the message content column or use an Identity column?

Comment: We can't know what consequences there are if there is a collision. Following matts link above, it says md5 can hit a collision if you do 6 billion hashes a second for 100 years. Is this an acceptable risk for you? If not you can choose SHA512 which would have even higher astronomical odds of a collision. Again you have to ask yourself if this is an acceptable risk. If not then do a bucket approach that has been mentioned below by Andre. We can't tell you how important your data is to you, it's a judgment call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do. If you are expecting messages to never be intentionally tampered with, even CRC64 will do just fine.

If you want a .NET provided solution that is fast and provides no cryptographic security, MD5 is just fine and will work for what you need.

If you need to determine if a message is different from another, and you expect someone to tamper with the data in transit and it may potentially be modified with bit twiddling techniques to force a hash collision, you should use SHA-256 or SHA-512.

Collisions *shouldn't* be a problem unless you are hashing billions of messages or someone is tampering with the data in transit. If someone is tampering with the data in transit, you have bigger problems.

Comment: The thing with collisions is WHY would you use the option that may one day blow into your face (even though the odds are against it) when a options without such drawback are available?

Comment: @Puciek Well, even SHA-512 has a probability of collisions. Typically hash based search systems are developed off of the bucket concept. You have many items which have the same function and they are categorized by that hash, not identified. Then you conduct a linear search against the bucket which results in an O(1) and then an O(N) effort but with a far smaller domain than you would have had originally. You have to weigh risk vs reward and consider intended functionality and then define error conditions to keep things within the bounds of that functionality. This is the basis of all good dev.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Gray Which is why I would recommend just implementing a bucket system at the database level too. Put an Index on the Hash, to speed things up. Minimal effort, maximum reward.

Comment: @AndréSnedeHansen Yeah but with bucketing, MD5 is really heavyweight. If you want to avoid bucketing, you should just use MD5 and assume it's always unique and take that risk. CRC32 or CRC64 and bucketing would be more appropriate. `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` uses the lightweight `GetHashCode`, but that won't work if you want to persist it to a database.

Answer (score 3):

You could implement it the way that [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) implements it. The Bucket system.

Have a Hash value in the database, and store the raw data.

```
----------------
| Hash | Value |
----------------
```

By searching through the hashes first the query will be faster, and if there are multiple hits, as there at some point will be with [`MD5`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5), you can just iterate through them, and match them more closely to see if they really are the same.

But as [Michael J. Gray](https://stackoverflow.com/users/468904/michael-j-gray) says, the probability of a collision is very small, on smaller datasets.

Comment: thanks Andre, if i could split the accept answer, then i would of

Comment: @CSharpNewBee Don't worry, glad I could be of some help :)

Comment: @CSharpNewBee I'll offset it with an upvote, since this brought up bucketing before I did.