# Easiest way in Java to turn String into UUID

Tags: java, uuid

How to generate a valid UUID from a String? The String alone is not what I'm looking for. Rather, I'm looking for something like a hash function converting any String to a valid UUID.

Comment: Well what are your requirements around uniqueness etc? You *could* just call `hashCode` to get an `int`, and then build a UUID based on that... but you'd obviously get a lot more collisions than necessary.

Comment: What's in the string that has any relevance to a UUID at all? You may as well just generate a new UUID and keep a mapping table somewhere. Or possibly [`UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(string.getBytes())`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#nameUUIDFromBytes(byte[])).

Comment: This looks like an XY Problem.

Comment: There is a good answer on this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40230410/1174024

Answer (score 31):

Try this out:

```
String superSecretId = "f000aa01-0451-4000-b000-000000000000";
UUID.fromString(superSecretId);
```

I am using this in my project and it works. Make sure you import the right stuff.

Comment: This method only converts from a string representation of UUID to UUID. Does not work for any string.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#toString--

Comment: This is not what the op asked for.

Comment: This doesn't hash __ANY__ string into an UUID

Answer (score 17):

In the Java core library, there's [`java.util.UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(byte[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#nameUUIDFromBytes-byte:A-).

I wouldn't recommend it because it's UUID 3 which is based on MD5, a very broken hash function. You'd be better off finding an implementation of UUID 5, which is based on SHA-1 (better although also [sort of broken](https://konklone.com/post/why-google-is-hurrying-the-web-to-kill-sha-1)).

Comment: any js equivalent?

Comment: @Abhijeet I wouldn't know. You may want to ask that as a separate question.

Comment: MD5 is broken for security purposes, but for hashing is good, has [low collision rate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201705/how-many-random-elements-before-md5-produces-collisions)