# Unique hex for unique string in java

Tags: java, hex

I want to get a unique hex per unique string. As of now I am using Message Digest class but there are possibilities (very less but still) that for two unique strings, computed hex can be same. So is there any other way to do such thing so that I have unique hex for unique strings.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you mean `hash`? If so: No way. There aren't enough different `int` values to match each string to a different one. Also, `hash` is not meant to be unique. Why do you need truly unique hashes?

Comment: what do you mean by "unique hex"? Hexadecimal is a number system ....

Comment: Transform your string to bytes using UTF8, then encode the bytes to Hex. You'll have a unique value.

Comment: i think you meant "format to hex" because there is no encode being done ... at all. But yes : this will of course retrieve unique hexadecimal number-sequences for unique strings

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming that you meant `hash`, not `hex`, since you mentioned [MessageDigest](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html)).

You can't have a unique hash code for each unique string. Think of it this way: A [hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) maps a string (or any other object) to an integer number. Since each integer number can be represented as a string, e.g. `"123"`, there are *at least as many* strings as there are different integer numbers -- and then some more, like, everything that is not a number, e.g. `"Hello"`. Thus, as there are more strings than integer numbers, it is not possible to generate unique hash codes for unique strings in all cases.

Having said that, for "everyday hashing" (for hash-tables etc.), the hash function provided by [`String.hashCode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode%28%29) is about as good as it gets. For [cryptographic hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function), `MessageDigest` seems to be the way to go. Depending on what you currently use, you might be able to upgrade to a stronger algorithm, though, e.g. `sha-512` instead of `sha-256`.

Comment: See also [Pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).

Comment: String.hashCode() is not in the same league as MessageDigest at all. Finding conflicts for hashCode() is trivial (and has, BTW, constituted the principle of DOS attacks), whereas MessageDigest is a cryptographic hash, for which finding conflicts is almost impossible. hashCode() produces an int (32 bits). A MessageDigest typically produces 16-20 bytes.

Comment: @JBNizet Still, I'd assume that if you want an `int`, then `String.hashCode` is okay? Or has it major flaws that were never fixed, maybe for compatibility reasons?

Comment: It's OK to have as unique as possible integers, but conflicts are easy to obtain. If unicity is the goal, 32 bits are not enough.

Comment: @JBNizet every checksum of any kind will always produce collisions within a finite amount of time, no matter the circumstances - "almost impossible" is highly exagerrated, one can even produce collisions for UUIDs pretty easily and the same is true for `MessageDigest` - the basic assumption around checksums is : `the end-user is not explicitly searching for collisions` hence most modern checksum-algorithms are pretty sufficient, during the lifespan of most apps and webapps collisions are `unlikely` to occur - but its certainly **not** `almost impossible`

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201705/how-many-random-elements-before-md5-produces-collisions. To find a collision with MD5, for example, which is weak and now considered broken, you would have, on average, to hash 6 billion files per second for 100 years. That's what I would call "almost impossible".

Comment: apparently you dont seem to grasp the difference between "actively searching for collisions / bruteforcing / exploiting algorithms" and "likelihood of passively encountered collision"

Comment: OK, so I'll rephrase: MessageDigest is a cryptographic hash, for which **encountering** conflicts is almost impossible. Finding collisions, by actively searching for them is extremely hard: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3049/are-there-any-known-collisions-for-the-sha-2-family-of-hash-functions. Prove me wrong: I let you 7 days to find a collision , with SHA256, for the hash of "hello world".

Comment: yea you definitely need a reality check sometime, but feel free to live in your internet forum world for now ...

Comment: @specializt , JBNizet Guys, is this still related to my post? If not, could you duke this out somewhere else, please? Chat, maybe?

Comment: im not "duking out" anything.

Answer (score 0):

Convert each character to a hex value:

```
String hex = Arrays.stream(str.split(""))
  .map(s -> s.charAt(0) + 0)
  .map(c -> String.format("%4x", c))
  .collect(Collectors.joining(""));
```

Comment: That won't compile, and it wouldn't necessary produce unique strings if it compiled, because no left-padding is used. For example, the chars [1, 0] would produce the same value as the chars [16]

Comment: @jbn yes, I realised the padding thing as soon as I wrote it. I've changed it to string format hex with width. And the compile thing - well yeah... I think I fixed that too. (A little busy putting kids to bed :/)