# Convert Alphanumeric value to a unique numeric value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table column with values like below

```
V5H 3K3
V6L 4L4
V4E 5L2
V5H 3K3
```

I need to get a unique number against each of them so it would look something like

```
V5H 3K3    1111
V6L 4L4    2222
V4E 5L2    3333
V5H 3K3    1111
```

Is there a simple function in SQL Server that can be used to do this?

Comment: Does it _have_ to be `1111, 2222, ...` or do you just need _some_ unique number? e.h. could it be `1, 2, 3, 1`?

Comment: oh sure.. that should do

Comment: You could treat it as a base 36 number and look for base 36 decoding functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Select cast(HashBytes('MD5', 'V5H 3K3') as int)
```

Returns
-381163718

For Example

```
Declare @Table table (SomeField varchar(25))
Insert into @Table values
('V5H 3K3'),
('V6L 4L4'),
('V4E 5L2'),
('V5H 3K3')

Select *,AsAnInt = abs(cast(HashBytes('MD5', SomeField) as int))
 From  @Table
```

Returns

```
SomeField   AsAnInt
V5H 3K3     381163718
V6L 4L4     245350301
V4E 5L2     1706996605
V5H 3K3     381163718
```

Comment: It doesn't guarantee uniqueness of mapping though. There is a possibility of hash collisions.

Comment: @MartinSmith Agreed, I should have qualified that.  That said, I've yet to witness a collision

Comment: According to this answer it is indeed massively improbable with MD5 http://stackoverflow.com/a/288519/73226

Comment: @MartinSmith  Great link!   I can live with those odds.