# probability of collision in MD5

Tags: md5

Worst case, I have 180 million values in a cache(15 minute window before they go stale) and an MD5 has 2^128 values.  What is my probability of a collision?  or better yet, is there a web page somewhere to answer that question or a rough estimate thereof?  That would rock so I know my chances.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How many random elements before MD5 produces collisions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201705/how-many-random-elements-before-md5-produces-collisions)

Comment: I am curious did you end up using MD5 for your use case ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The probability is *1-m!/(mⁿ(m-n)!)* where *m = 2¹²⁸* and *n = 180000000*.

Running it through on-line Wolfram exceeds available computational time!

If you have SmallTalk installed locally, you can run this:

```
|m n p|

m := 2 raisedTo:128.
n := 180000000.
p := (1-(m factorial/((m raisedTo:n)*(m-n)factorial)))asFloat.

Transcript show:p printString;cr.
```

A search for the Birthday Problem brings up a [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) where they provide a table showing for 128 bits and 2.6×10¹⁰ hashes, the probability of a collision is 1 in 10¹⁸, so that’s for 140× the number of hashes than what you’re considering. So you know your odds are “worse” than this.

A good approximation if *n ≪ m* is *1-e<sup>-n<sup>2</sup>/2m</sup>*, where if you plug in *m* and *n* above, you get 4.76×10⁻²³ or 1 in 2.10×10²² as the probability of a collision.

Even though the probability of a collision is very low, it is prudent in the `FOOBAR` case, say if there is an issue and the hashes accumulate for more than 15 minutes, to at least confirm what would happen in the event of a collision. This will also help if someone somehow injects duplicate hashes in order to try to compromise it.