# How to convert string to integer in PHP?

Tags: php, converters

(This question is **not** about PHP type-casting.)

I have read in couple of questions what it is best not to show record id to users, but use another value, which doesn't  give out any information about howmany record there is in the database, etc. I wanted to implement this, and after searching on google, surprisingly no solution was found.

So, my question is, is it possible to convert a (long, for example) sequence of strings to unique (or unique enough for at least million converts) sequence of numbers, is there any options available which I have no idea of?
Just to show you an example:

```
 $uName = $this->newUsername;
 $publicId = $this->strToInt(somecomplexstring); // Outputs something like 13272992
 // Or feed with username
 $publicId = $this->strToInt($uName);
```

Comment: You could use uniqueid

Comment: Surely your question is back to front change the numerical ID `(integer)` into a human readable string that doesn't reveal the number of indexes ? How would your complex string tell me how many records there are?

Comment: uniqid — Generate a unique ID    echo uniqid();

Comment: I know, but you do realize what it generates  random sequence of alphanumeric characters? While this is an option (even though it's output is quite long), I am looking to function which could output a sequence of integers by input string.

Comment: @Luke Thanks for the idea (about converting integer to string). Complex stringis just a unique sequence of numbers and letters.

Answer (score 1):

You might considering using something like a slug. So your user will have an unique id in the database but also an unique slug (random string, ex. TGqJItemU5TGqJItemU5f6S5VaCr2n). You can then use this slug instead of the id when presenting data to the browser.

Comment: True, that is indeed another option

Answer (score 0):

As stated in a comment, you can use [`uniquid`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) to get a unique string. this function will return an hexadecimal string.

If you need only numbers, you just have to convert the hex to a decimal number with this [`hexdec`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php).

The final code will look like this :

```
hexdec(uniqid());
```

---

An other way to get an integer from a string is to use [`md5`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php). This function also returns a hex string so you will have to use hexdec to get a decimal number

Please note that a md5 is not a unique string, there is a (very small) probability of accidental collision (1 in 340 undecillion, see [How many random elements before MD5 produces collisions ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/288519/3992945) for more info)

Comment: Thanks, I will look into hexdec function

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

md5(uniqid(rand(), true))

Comment: I a not talking about variable types

Comment: He wants to hide the number of records so user 150 doesn't know he's user 150