# Does name based UUID satisfy those conditions?

Tags: uuid

For some reason, I have to make UUIDs that are same when same strings are input like below.

```java
UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(str.getBytes());
```

What I want to know is this new UUID satisfy below conditions.

- As far as input strs are same, I can get the same generated UUIDs.
- As far as input strs are different, the generated UUIDs must be different.
- Is there any chance that randomly created UUIDs that are created by Time-based UUID can be duplicate with this new UUID.

I checked those in the UUID docs but I want a more confirmation as deployment without those conditions can make our system disaster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### "As far as str is same, I can get the same UUID"

Yes, as defined in the [RFC 4122 - 4.3. Algorithm for Creating a Name-Based UUID](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4122#page-13):

> The requirements for these types of UUIDs are as follows:
>
> - The UUIDs generated at different times from the same name in the same namespace MUST be equal.

### "As far as input strs are different, the UUIDs must be different."

Yes ([and no](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)), as defined in the [RFC 4122 - 4.3. Algorithm for Creating a Name-Based UUID](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4122#page-13):

> [...]
>
> The UUIDs generated from two different names in the same namespace
> should be different (with very high probability).

Practically, different byte arrays results in different UUIDs. But there have been MD5 collisions, therefore the mentioned "with very high probability".

### "Is there any chance that randomly created UUIDs that are created by Time-based UUID can be duplicate with this new UUID."

No, the name-based UUID have the version number set to `3` (or `5`), the time based UUID have the version set to `1`.

Comment: Do you know how much exactly the probability is?

Comment: @이창권 The probability of finding two inputs with the same MD5 hash is so low that you shouldn't be concerned about it. See other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201705/how-many-random-elements-before-md5-produces-collisions and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155008/how-unique-is-uuid